# Basil plant pot sprouted this. What is it? Arugula?

Tags: identification

I've got a couple of basil plants I bought at the local grocery sitting by my kitchen window for a couple of months now. I just noticed this one does not look like basil.....Is it Arugula?
[image: Arugula?]
[image: what am I?]
[image: Arugula2 Electric Boogaloo?]

Comment: With any luck you will be able to make a nice tomato and basil salad from the pot.

Answer (score 10):

That's a tomato plant. You'll need to get it out of the pot with the basil or it will out-compete it. If it's warm enough - and if you have space outside - you could water the plants thoroughly, wait a few hours for the mix to dry a bit, then carefully unpot the plants and carefully untangle their roots. Move the tomato into you the ground outside and give it some support and you'll have free veggies in a couple of months at the latest.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and help identifying the tomato plant!

Comment: I had to look up 'arugula' and found it's what we call 'rocket' in England.

Comment: Tomato seeds are exceptionally tenacious and will survive composting with regularity, so if you've ever had tomatoes in your garden, be prepared to always have them.

Comment: @TomW  Definitely. When I moved into my current house there was a decades' old compost heap in the backyard; the previous owners never used it, so it was basically soil at that point. I wanted to move the piles to a new location, so I spread it out and created an ornamental garden. A couple of years after I spread it out, a tomato seedling sprouted in the flowers; it turned out to be a red cherry tomato. This was 8 years after we moved in and probably 14+ years since the compost heap had last been used - we had never planted a red cherry tomato. That seed was maybe15 years old when it sprouted

Comment: @Jurp - Or, the seed was from leftovers of a tasty snack recently (at the time) carried into your yard from a neighbors garden, by a squirrel or some other (small) animal. (To be honest, I don't know if squirrels eat tomatoes.) In my experience, viable tomato seeds that are in damp/wet conditions in an appropriate temperature range will begin to sprout in a few days to a couple weeks. To have sprouted after being in the ground for nearly 15 years, it would have to have been kept completely dry the entire time.

Comment: @KevinFegan Your hypothesis is what I would've expected myself. None of my near neighbors, however, grow or have grown cherry tomatoes in my entire time in this house. I was quite frankly shocked when I saw the tomato and doubly shocked when I saw that it was a red cherry. FWIW I still have Grandpa Ott's morning glories sprouting every year, even though I have never planted them.Those seeds are at least 9 years' old because every year I pull the plants before they set seed. Some plants are resilient.

Answer (score 1):

It's a tomato. Possibly you got it through somebody's compost that included kitchen scraps from somebody's salad. A careful soil prep process would heat the compost to kill all the seeds. Maybe one snuck through.

If you want to keep the tomato, it probably wants more light than it is getting inside. It is looking fairly spindly and very soft. If there is a place outside that you can put the pot, it's probably better. If so, you want to gradually introduce the plant to outdoors. Put it out in bright sun for a half hour the first day, then an hour the next, and so on.

If the seed it grew from was a commercial variety, it is possible you won't get much in the way of tomatoes even in the best conditions. They are often crosses that don't breed true. A lot of commercial veggies and fruit are like that. You get nice big tomatoes from this generation, then a really disappointing crop from the next.

Answer (score 0):

It's tomato! Tomato and basil grow quite well together, and basil protects the tomato from pests, so (assuming it's warm enough where you live) you could try planting both of them outside together in a sunny spot. If you do make sure that they're spread apart enough that they have space to develop their own root systems.

Comment: There's no scientific study that I'm aware of that shows basil protecting anything from pests. If you know if one, please post a link for a citation.

Comment: Especially seeing that our basil and tomato plants, both have pests :-)  The only study I heard of was where they concluded that the extra fragrance of such plants may divert the pests to them.  But that's a very dicey proposition.